# When do I need to delete pointers, and when do I need to set them to 0?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a CS student learning about C++.

This is a general question, but the particular example I'm working with is making a linked list that will have nodes to store string pointers.

```
class LinkNode {
public:
    friend class Stack;
    LinkNode* next;
    std::string* data;
    LinkNode(std::string* data, LinkNode* next) :data(data), next(next) { ; }
}
```

If I'm using pointers, then shouldn't I have a destructor that calls `delete` on both the `next` and `data`?

```
~LinkNode() {
    delete this->data;
    delete this->next;
}
```

The code used in my educational material as well as samples across the internet all neglect to include this (even though we do use destructors in other contexts). I'm trying to understand why this would not be required in this case.

And, quite relatedly: if I'm using a pointer to delete something, do I have to set the pointer to null?

I often see people write a deletion out like this this:

```
delete ptr;
ptr = 0;
```

From what I understand the purpose of setting it to 0 is just to prevent it from being accidentally used, as after the `delete` it now points to an invalid memory address.

So if I'm calling `delete` at the end of a function where the pointer will fall out of scope anyway, like in a pop function or the destructor, can I omit that line? Do people just include it out of habit?

Comment: Arguably you shouldn’t use pointers at all. And then you don’t need to worry about this.

Comment: Every object that was `new`ed should be `delete`d. That is the only requirement. Where and how the `delete` happens is immaterial. However, unless certain best practices are followed, achieving this lofty goal becomes pretty much impossible, and memory corruption ahoy! It is true that if nothing gets `delete`d at the end of the program, the program ends, and that's the end of it. However, unless proper memory management skills are learned, the chances of moving on to bigger and better C++ things will be quite slim.

Comment: Actually, it's quite simple: `delete` what you created with `new`, and `delete[]` what you created with `new[]`. To organize this properly and prevent memory leaks (annoying) or double deleting (Undefined Behavior) is sometimes not that simple. Thus, at best, you don't use `new` anymore but prefer the modern replacements for this. (Even productive code can be written nowadays without any literal `new`/`delete`.)

Comment: _So if I'm calling delete at the end of a function where the pointer will fall out of scope anyway_ What if an exception is thrown in the middle of your function (by something you're calling) so that the end of function is not reached?

Comment: @Scheff Is your intention to say that I don't need to `delete` these string pointers because I didn't use the `new` keyword?

Comment: @Floryn A linked list usually allocates it's nodes on the heap. Additionally having each node allocate it's resource on the heap is not needed. It just makes the code less performant and more error prone.

Comment: @Scheff "What if an exception is thrown in the middle of your function so that the end of function is not reached?" — I would think this makes no difference between then the `delete` statement is not even being reached.

Comment: @Biffen Do you mean I should use smart pointers? I'm aware there is such a thing that handles memory deletion for you, but my goal for now is understanding regular pointers and I assume we'll use smart pointers eventually.

Comment: @super I'm not sure what your comment is meaning to say: I should never use a linked list to store pointers?

Comment: @Floryn I mean that having a `std::string*` in your node is bad. You gain nothing from it. Use a `std::string` instead. Then you don't have to deal with `new/delete` for it. `std::string` is movable, so there is almost never a reason to allocate it on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

- `delete` pointers pointing to a valid object/variable to destroy them and free space.
- Set them to `NULL`, `nullptr` or `0` (quite the same) so you can identify them as unused.

You see, if you just `delete` the object, **the pointer itself doesn't change**, so now it's pointing to a invalid space of memory. If you are never again going to use that pointer, then that's not a big deal, but otherwise it could be **very** problematic.

So setting it to `null` allows you to perform checks on your pointer and be sure whether your pointer is being used or not.

---

Also, to answer as your first question, and as pointed out in the comments, you have to call `delete` on the pointers that you have created with `new`.

- So, let's say that the `data` pointers of your example point to a string created **outside** of the list (so it behaves like a list of references). In that case that pointer is not in charge to manage its content and should not be deleted.
- But if, for example, each time you add a new node, you did `data = new string("whatever");`, then yes, you should delete them in the destructor.

Comment: I would phrase the portion about null pointers a bit differently: **if** your design calls for using a null pointer to signify the absence of a resource then you should set the pointer to null. That avoids the silly code that some folks write: `~my_class() { delete ptr; ptr = 0; }`. +1.

Comment: Also, `delete` whatever you `new`ed. Pointers that point at things that were not created with `new` should not be deleted.

Comment: @PeteBecker So, just to be as clear as can be, the non-silly version of that destructor is `~my_class() { delete ptr; }`?

Comment: I try to not think 'good code' means only doing what's strictly necessary. I ask if the `= 0;` can be omitted to understand if that is indeed its only function. But I sometimes get the impression from people it's good practice to just do it anyway, even in cases where it seems clear the pointer won't be used again.

Comment: @Floryn -- yes. Setting `ptr` to 0 doesn't accomplish anything, because it's about to go away. Also, while I'm at it, `if (ptr) delete ptr;` isn't necessary. `delete` can deal with null pointers.

Comment: Already edited the question to include that, thanks @PeteBecker